# Eclipse XML Template with multiple ${cursor}?

Tags: xml, eclipse, templates

I am writing some XML templates to speed up writing schemas. I was wondering if it is possible to do a "create element" with multiple cursor locations akin to Eclipse generating a method in a java class which allows you to tab through the return type, method name, and parameters (they appear selected by a rectangle).

Here is the template I tried out:

`<xs:element name="${cursor}" type="${cursor}" />`

It moves the cursor to the name attribute, but I can't tab to the type attribute. Is there a way to do this with xml in eclipse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extracted from [eclipseonetips](http://www.eclipseonetips.com/2009/11/29/how-to-tweak-eclipse-templates-to-suit-you/), it works for me:

```
<xs:element name="${whateverUniqueNameYouWant}" type="${cursor}" />
```